# Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete LocalVariableDeclaration occurs

Tags: java, syntax

```
public class Water {
    private Graphic graphic;
    private float speed;
    private float distanceTraveled;

    public Water(float x, float y, float direction) 
    {
        speed = 0.7f;

        graphic = new Graphic();
        graphic.setType("WATER");   

        graphic.setX(x);
        graphic.setY(y);

        direction = graphic.getDirection(); //direction from Hero as water is fired
    }
    public Water update(int time) 
    {
        graphic.draw();
        return Water.this;
        distanceTraveled; // this is where the error occured...
    }
}
```

When I tried to call `distanceTraveled`, I am getting the error as:

> Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete LocalVariableDeclaration

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but `distanceTraveled` is a variable, not a method. And you `return` before! There can't be a statement after returning.

Comment: @mnille yes distanceTraveled is a variable and I tried to call it before the return or even delete the return but i still keep getting the same error...

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you right. What do you expect by "calling" `distanceTraveled`? What do you want to happen?

Comment: @mnille I am just trying to pass a value into distanceTraveled such as distanceTraveled = 1; but now I am not able to do that.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the Syntax error disappear and to assign a value to `distanceTraveled`modify the method `public Water update(int time)` as follows:

```
public Water update(int time) {
    graphic.draw();
    distanceTraveled = 1; // assign a value before returning
    return Water.this;
}
```

Maybe you should read a bit about Java and doing some tutorials, because this is very basic stuff (at least if I'm not getting you wrong).

Comment: same issue but different scenario, can anyone please help :-
public class InterfaceInsideClass 
{

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  ClassO.inner.i;         // Error occurs here
 }
}

class ClassO
{
 interface inner
 {
  int i=10;
 }
}

Comment: @bharatbhushan: I think here you have multiply issues. First you have an interface which you cannot use for an assignment directly. You should have a class which implements the interface. Member variables in interfaces are `final`, so even you could use an interface for an assignment you were not allowed to change the value of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either print distanceTraveled or do any operation like increment. Don't write only variable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**CORRECT: <%!  ...code... %>** (JSP DECLARATION)

**WRONG  : <%   ...code... %>** (JSP SCRIPLET)

**WRONG  : <%=  ...code... %>** (JSP EXPRESSION)

**Example:**

```
<!-- ------------------------------------- -->
<html><body><h1> 
    <%!
    public static String fn(){

        return( "[CORRECT:USE ! MARK]");
    }; 
    %>

    <%= fn() %>
</h1></body></html>
<!-- ------------------------------------- -->
```

Using **"<%"** or **"<%="** instead of **"<%!"** will get error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: [3] in the jsp file: [/index.jsp] Syntax
>   error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete
>   LocalVariableDeclaration